# fractional part of the square of natural number

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fractional-part

How can if prove that the sequence :$$a_n\:=\left\{\sqrt{n}\right\}\left(fractional\:part\:of\:\sqrt{n}\right)\:=\:\:\sqrt{n}\:-\:\left[\sqrt{n}\right]$$
is bounded from above by 1?
So far i try induction but its nothing that the assumption can help me for the "step" of the induction so i kind of stuck here.
tnx!

*($[x]$ - the floor function of x)

Comment: What is the "fractional part" of $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: I guess the fractional part $\mathrm{frac}$ is meant to be defined as $\mathrm{frac}\left(n\right) := \sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor$ with $\mathrm{frac}\left(n\right)\in\left[0,1\right[$ by definition of the floor function.

Comment: @5xum $\sqrt{n}\:-\:\left[\sqrt{n}\right]$

Comment: Isn't the fractional part $\ge 0$ and $<1$ by definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fractional part of a number is, by definition, between $0$ and $1$. This is because $[x]$, the integer part of $x$, is defined as

> The largest integer $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $n<x$.

Therefore, if $x-[x] > 1$, then $[x]+1$ is:

- smaller than $x$ (because $x-[x]>1$ can be rearanged to $x>[x]+1$)
- larger than $[x]$ (by definition, it is larger by $1$.

meaning that $[x]$ is *not* the largest integer satisfying $n<x$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that by definition fractional parts should always be less then $1$.

To get an idea of why this happens just note that any real number $x$ can be written in the form $$x=I.a_1a_2\ldots$$

for example $\dfrac{1}{3}=0.3333\ldots$ and so here $I=0$ and $a_i=3$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$.

Hence $\left [x\right]=I$

Therefore $$x-\left [x\right]=I.a_1a_2\ldots-I=0.a_1a_2\ldots=\{x\}$$

Can we now conclude that $0\le\{x\}<1$? When does the equality arise?